# Converting dict to list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a nested dict which parsed into produce a single list.

Here is the working code: [code in ideone](https://ideone.com/pBvZ13) 
But couple of braces are missing.

The expected result should be:

```
[['>=', 'qty', '3'], 'AND', ['in', 'category_ids', '240']]
```

where as I am getting

```
[['>=', 'qty', '3', 'AND', ['in', 'category_ids', '240']]]
```

```
def aggregatorConvert(aggregator):
        if aggregator == "any":
            return "OR"
        else:
            return "AND"

def operatorSymbol(operator):
        if operator == "{}":
            return "in"
        elif operator == "!{}":
            return "not in"
        else:
            return operator

def expression_tuple(query):
    if query.get("attribute"):
        exp = []
        exp.append(operatorSymbol(query.get("operator")))
        exp.append(query.get("attribute"))
        exp.append(query.get("value"))
        return exp
    else:
        return []


def format_serialized(query, counter):
    counter = counter or 0
    ex = expression_tuple(query)
    conditions = query.get("conditions")
    if conditions:
        for i in query.get("conditions"):
            if ex:
                ex.append(aggregatorConvert(query.get("aggregator")))
            ex.append(format_serialized(query.get("conditions")[i], counter + 1))
    print ex
    return ex


query = {'type': 'salesrule/rule_condition_combine', 'aggregator': 'all', 'operator': None, 'attribute': None, 'conditions': {0: {'type': 'salesrule/rule_condition_product_subselect', 'aggregator': 'all', 'operator': '>=', 'attribute': 'qty', 'conditions': {0: {'operator': '{}', 'attribute': 'category_ids', 'type': 'salesrule/rule_condition_product', 'is_value_processed': False, 'value': '240'}}, 'is_value_processed': None, 'value': '3'}}, 'is_value_processed': None, 'value': '1'}
format_serialized(query, 0)
```

Can someone tell me where I have gone wrong ?

Comment: can you show your nested dict too???

Comment: @Hackaholic Its right at the bottom, the "query" variable.

Comment: There are no *"extra brackets"* - instead of a list containing strings and lists of strings, you have a list containing a single list of strings and lists of strings.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes. I should have phrased it correctly. Let me edit the post as This is my expected result: [['>=', 'qty', '3'], 'AND', ['in', 'category_ids', '240']] and this is what I am getting [['>=', 'qty', '3', 'AND', ['in', 'category_ids', '240']]] . How to achieve the same ? Is this help you understanding the issue ?

Comment: Why do you expect the expected result and not the actual result?

Comment: @interjay so that I can match those expression on a given set of values

Comment: That's not what I'm asking. I'm asking why you think the result you got is wrong for the given input.

Comment: @interjay I was hoping to get the list like what I expected, but the program is correct as it gives what it is supposed to do. but I am asking any chance I can modify that to suit my requirement ?

Comment: Yes, you can change the program to be `print [['>=', 'qty', '3'], 'AND', ['in', 'category_ids', '240']]` and it will give the expected output. I don't see why you expect this output for the given input though, so there's no way to answer your question unless you actually explain this.

Comment: The given input is a nested dict. I want to crawl through it and construct a new List through that. The list that I asked for is to ease the later development,as in I can get the all the expression in the List by looping through it, But if the actual result is given to me then I am not sure how to get the first expression as it is embedded as items not a list.

Comment: Sigh... You're still not explaining *how* the dict should be translated to the list. As far as I can see, `'240'` is on a deeper nesting level than `'3'` in the dict, so it makes sense for it to be the same in the list. Unless you can explain why it shouldn't be, this question is meaningless and should be closed.

Comment: @interjay Ohh I get it now. Sorry for the misunderstanding. I have passed with a new dict and the result shows what I was missing in this one. https://ideone.com/EvbagW .

Comment: @interjay Could you answer so that I can accept it and close this ?

Comment: Are you saying that the result you got above was actually fine, and there is no problem with the code? Maybe you should just delete the question if so.

Comment: Yes. Well let it be here only if somebody needs it. And btw I will make a summary of what you said and answer it if you don't want to.

Comment: @PranayaBehera how do you expect this to be of any use to anybody else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is nested and I would think that the result you are getting would be the *right* result, perserving the nesting. However, if you want to flatten it out and remove the nesting you can use tail recursion to generate your result.

This is your query pretty printed:

```
query = {
    'type': 'salesrule/rule_condition_combine', 
    'aggregator': 'all', 
    'operator': None, 
    'attribute': None, 
    'conditions': {
        0: {
            'type': 'salesrule/rule_condition_product_subselect', 
            'aggregator': 'all', 
            'operator': '>=', 
            'attribute': 'qty', 
            'conditions': {
                0: {
                    'operator': '{}', 
                    'attribute': 'category_ids', 
                    'type': 'salesrule/rule_condition_product', 
                    'is_value_processed': False, 
                    'value': '240'
                    }
                }, 
            'is_value_processed': None, 
            'value': '3'
        }
    }, 
    'is_value_processed': None, 
    'value': '1'
    }
```

If you construct your result like so:

```
import copy
def format_serialized(query, counter, lst):
    counter = counter or 0
    ex = expression_tuple(query)
    if ex:
        lst.append(copy.copy(ex)) # you need to copy the list since it is mutable
    conditions = query.get("conditions")
    if conditions:
        for i in query.get("conditions"):
            if ex:
                lst.append(aggregatorConvert(query.get("aggregator")))
            format_serialized(query.get("conditions")[i], counter + 1, lst)
    return lst
```

and call it like so:

```
print format_serialized(query, 0, [])
```

You will get:

```
[['>=', 'qty', '3'], 'AND', ['in', 'category_ids', '240']]
```

Which is the expected result. The difference in implementation is that you pass the list into your recursive function and construct it 'on the way down' rather than 'on the way up'.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your query assignment with:

```
    query = {'type': 'salesrule/rule_condition_combine', 'aggregator': 'all', 'operator': None, 'attribute': None, 
    'conditions': {0: {'type': 'salesrule/rule_condition_product_subselect', 'aggregator': 'all', 'operator': '>=', 'attribute': 'qty', 'is_value_processed': None, 'value': '3'}, 
        1: {'operator': '{}', 'attribute': 'category_ids', 'type': 'salesrule/rule_condition_product', 'is_value_processed': False, 'value': '240'}
    }, 'is_value_processed': None, 'value': '1'}
```

full example [here](http://repl.it/63V)

Comment: Thanks, but I can't change the query assignment. I don't have any control over that.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `ex=[ex]` before `ex.append(aggregatorConvert(query.get("aggregator")))` as:

```
if ex:
    ex=[ex]  # add this line
    ex.append(aggregatorConvert(query.get("aggregator")))
ex.append(format_serialized(query.get("conditions")[i], counter + 1)
```

This will fix the issue.